# How can I parse a Java proberty file with PHP?

Tags: java, php

oI have a Java proberties file which looks more or less like this:

```
FD6AEA14B3581255C5D40451CDFF8168.hash=90AD759FF0B41ABD7260EF1044E75330
FD6AEA14B3581255C5D40451CDFF8168.path=Volumes/UA08154711/08154711/Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing/Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing/07 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing (Album Version).mp3
EA3F9134319E314BC85D59D16122800.fileName=04 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing (Album Version).mp3
EA3F9134319E314BC85D59D16122800.hash=88302129514633AAED4553F1B0CCB6B8
EA3F9134319E314BC85D59D16122800.path=Volumes/UA08154711/08154711/Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing/Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing/04 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing (Album Version).mp3
EAFB12EE4094D48A2B1BD367E5737C80.fileName=._02 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing (Explicit Version).mp3
EAFB12EE4094D48A2B1BD367E5737C80.hash=34FB1D1E3523334A89D03DE707C00968
EAFB12EE4094D48A2B1BD367E5737C80.path=Volumes/UA08154711/08154711/Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing/Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing/._02 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing (Explicit Version).mp3
fileSize=1024595340
Number=03173729
```

the files destination is *files/03173729.meta*

I want to parse the file with php so I can save the data in the mySQL database. The code:

```
$filepath = "files/03173729.meta"; 
        $fileContents = file_get_contents("$filepath");
        echo $fileContents;

        $result = parse_properties($fileContents);

        //Fetch the contents from the result array and add them to the database

        function parse_properties($txtProperties) {
        $result = array();
        $lines = split("\n", $txtProperties);
        $key = "";
        $isWaitingOtherLine = false;
        foreach ($lines as $i => $line) {
            if (empty($line) || (!$isWaitingOtherLine && strpos($line, "#") === 0))
                continue;

            if (!$isWaitingOtherLine) {
                $key = substr($line, 0, strpos($line, '='));
                $value = substr($line, strpos($line, '=')+1, strlen($line));        
            }
            else {
                $value .= $line;    
            }    
            /* Check if ends with single '\' */
            if (strrpos($value, "\\") === strlen($value)-strlen("\\")) {
                $value = substr($value,0,strlen($value)-1)."\n";
                $isWaitingOtherLine = true;
            }
            else {
                $isWaitingOtherLine = false;
            }

            $result[$key] = $value;    
            unset($lines[$i]);        
        }

            return $result;


        }
```

But I do not know how to implement the file path into the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
<?php
    $filepath = "[your path]"; 
    $fileContents = file_get_contents("$filepath");

    $result = parse_preperties($fileContents);

    //Fetch the contents from the result array and add them to the database

    function parse_properties($txtProperties) {
     ...
     ...
     ...
     }
?>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you! I did like you said : `$filepath = "files/03173729.meta"; 
$fileContents = file_get_contents("$filepath");

$result = parse_preperties($fileContents);
echo $result;` But my page is white. Shouldn't I see something?

Comment: Do `echo $fileContents;` after `$fileContents =file_get_contents("$filepath");` just to make sure, you are getting the file data.

Comment: This is the var_dump of $result: `$filepath = "files/03173729.meta"; $fileContents = file_get_contents("$filepath"); $result = parse_preperties($fileContents); //Fetch the contents from the result array and add them to the database function parse_properties($txtProperties) { $result = array(); $lines = split("\n", $txtProperties); $key = ""; $isWaitingOtherLine = false; foreach ($lines as $i => $line) { if (empty($line) || (!$isWaitingOtherLine && strpos($line, "#") === 0)) continue; if (!$isWaitingOtherLine)`  I think I did something wrong. Sorry I am totally lost.

Comment: with `echo $fileContents;` I get the following result: `$filepath = "files/03173729.meta"; $fileContents = file_get_contents("$filepath"); echo $fileContents;`

Comment: Your output doesn't make any sense. Can you please update your question with your current code.

Comment: There's a typing mistake in this line: `$result = parse_preperties($fileContents);`. The spelling of `properties` is wrong.

Comment: And make sure, there is a folder named `files` in the directory where you have this php script and your meta file is inside it.

Comment: I changed the properties mistake and also checked the file is in the folder, still the same output

Comment: Are your PHP tags proper? Make sure there is no mistake over there. I tested the code on my side with your file. It works fine.

Comment: Oh yes, so stupid, there was a mistake in my php tag :/ Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I am glad, it helped you.. :)